# Failed to claim resource error

Tags: boot, grub2, busybox

I booted up my Linux Ubuntu. It popped first two messages, then kubuntu booting screen, then goes back to some "Boxy" program. The error messages above are:

```
Platform MSFT0101:00 Failed to claim resource 1
ACPI MSFT0101:00 Platform device creation failed: -16
USB 1-5: Device Descriptor Read/64, Error -71
USB 1-5: Device Descriptor Read/64, Error -71
USB 1-5: Device Descriptor Read/64, Error -71
```

There is lots of people with the same first error message but the second message varies in each post I visit.

Most of them suggest disabling something called "TPM" they link image to motherboard, no settings, no commands, no BIOS, straight up tampering with steel which I really don't want to do.

Other people cannot boot into computer at all (it happens before they can interact with dual boot). And they get no answer.

There's also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926738/cant-load-failed-to-claim-resource-1) post, which has instructions but for something called "watchdog" not "MSFT0101" and before I waste 3 hours going back and forth just to find out the commands don't work on my MSFT thing.

I'd rather create an entire post and know for certain, than execute commands and find out I formatted entire drive.

I am programmer, but I have little to no experience with Linux. Keep that in mind.

-- Greetings, J. Doe.

PS: Ask me any information you need.

Comment: Did it boot before or is this a live usb ? If it booted before, try booting an old kernel. https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version . Is secure boot enabled ?

Comment: It booted up for 2 years already. I even had it on today, I had to move, turned it off, I came back home to this. I did boot with older kernel didn't work. Secure boot doesn't appear to be a thing in my motherboard. Let me check. I'll toggle it.  Edit: I have a problem, I set password on it and I forgot it, although it did work before with same setting.

Answer (score 2):

My Acer Apsire S5 prints the same warning every time I boot Debian Buster.  I don't use TPM at home, so I disabled TPM in the BIOS to get rid of the warning.

To disable TPM in InsydeH20 BIOS:

Enter BIOS setup (press F2 during POST).  On the Security page, set a password for Supervisor to unlock TPM state.  Toggle TPM off.

Then clear the password Supervisor, select Set Supervisor Password, enter the current password, then press Enter twice to leave the new password blank.

Save and exit.