# Why does it keep sending me back to this menu when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I have an Acer V3-575 (~500 GB) and am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.1.  I got the ISO from the Ubuntu webpage and put it on my 64 GB USB for the bootable USB.

Whenever I click Restart Now to finish the installation, it goes back to when it started with the four options to Try Ubuntu Without Installing and Install Ubuntu.

If I take my bootable USB out right after I click Restart Now, it shows

```
[   0.00000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)
[   0.138817] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed0fff]
[   0.138824] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
```

If I wait a bit and then take it out before the menu pops up, my computer will tell me that no bootable device was detected.

I've tried taking it out before pressing Restart Now, but that just ends up with the first error.  I've tried it online, offline, Normal Installation, Minimal Installation, Erase and reinstall, Erase disk and install Ubuntu, and Something Else.

The operating system works just fine when I click Try Ubuntu Without Installing, but nothing sticks around after a restart.

I have tried to supply as much useful info as I could, but if you need any more, I'll get the information ASAP.

Thank you.

I'm using EFI.

Edit: I got it to work by following these instructions twice: [How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home).  I actually had to enable Secure Boot before changing the trusted for executing.  I'm rather new to this, and that search didn't occur to me.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? You are supposed to take out the USB and restart the machine, it's that simple.

Comment: I edited with that error.  When I pull it out at other times, it asks for a bootable device.

Comment: Those are relevant error messages. The first one seems to be just a warning. The others seem to be caused by the "Trusted Platform Module". If you can turn this off in the BIOS, please do and retry. See e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926738/cant-load-failed-to-claim-resource-1).

Comment: Set the supervisor password (in BIOS/UEFI settings), then set "trust" on the ubuntu boot files grubx64.efi, and shimx64.efi.  This is specific to Acer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home)