# HP laptop: Ubuntu install and live disk failed: pcie trouble: fixed

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

**the trouble:** after booting the live usb you get a choice to 'try' or 'install'. both will halt and only a hard reset solves this.

**what i tried:**
now there were some errors at boot that are visible if running the live usb fails:

[VMXdisabled-acpiwatchdog-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkr4K.jpg)

on this laptop you do not see the keyboard+puppet screen when booting, it just goes to loading ubuntu.
in safe mode it will hang at ubuntu, not showing the desktop with try/install dialog or mouse cursor.

and looking for a solution i tried disabling the TPM as stated here:
[Can't load, failed to claim resource: 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926738/cant-load-failed-to-claim-resource-1)

that did muck up my windows it did not give me the chance to install or run the live cd...and the device creation failed stayed at -16.
So I enabled TPM again and re-validated windows

Also enabled virtualisation, 1st 2 errors dissapeared device creation failed -16 is still present.
so i get to Try or Install and then it locks up.

what am i missing in settings of the hp? outside of the obvious like a battery management system that can limit charge level in bios so it won't destroy the battery for naught or even catch fire if kept plugged in.

Now there is a known issue with some (and this one) hp laptop models that when your power plan in windows has wifi set to max power savings it generates constant WHEA event 17 recoverable errors in the log and you have unstable or slow wifi/bluetooth.
the low power value for the bluetooth seems wrong.
if set to 'max performance' or 'min power savings' those WHEA errors will not be logged in event viewer on windows and wifi works as good or bad as designed.
There will still be one WHEA error 17 in the event viewer at each boot telling you the pci express root port has a corrected hardware error.

Maybe this is related to why ubuntu won't install or try on this laptop?

Comment: What exactly was the laptop model? This info might really help people searching.

Comment: this is done on a hp pavilion 13-x360 , but when i searched for a solution i found spectre, elitebook and some other models suffering from the same thing.
since the hardware gives a lower power value for either bluetooth or wifi than it is capable of using that hardware will time out or be unresponsive when that profile is used. apparantly ubuntu does not overcome faulty labeled hardware by disabling the energy saving settings and trying again.

Comment: with a rtl8723be wifi/bluetooth card with only one antenna connected (and still marketing as 'N' wifi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION**: try installing by first accessing the GRUB menu and pressing <kbd>e</kbd> to get the editor, and there adding:

```
pcie_aspm=off
```

after `splash` to the line beginning with `linux`. (it should look like: `splash pcie_aspm=off ---`).

save and exit

This at least makes it possible to use 'try' and then after putting Bluetooth and WiFi to 'off' it would run the installer (install alongside Windows).

After request to remove USB drive for reboot it alas didn't start up in the Ubuntu boot menu, but went straight to Windows.

after changing boot order I was able to change the `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"
```

run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot once more.

And now the system can be connected, updated and works stable and reliable... I hope it helps you too.

It's too bad Linux only has settings for off or automatic in pcie_aspm. So from now on it's all full on!

If somebody, after reading this, knows of a solution so you can set the minimum aspm pcie (wifi) state in ubuntu i'm all ears, since one or 2 steps less (L1.0 or L1.1) makes up to 80% less energy usage when not in use. (from >400 mW to <30 mW) and on a laptop that's still a big deal.

But it might be an addition to a new distro, to include a safe mode that sets Active State Power Management to off.

Answer (score 0):

HP generally has issues running Linux OS.
If your PC/Laptop has a dedicated graphics, then select safe graphics mode to dualboot ubuntu (any version). Also what worked for me, was running ubuntu live from the USB Stick and then clicking on Install Ubuntu. It even gives you a quick tab to install Ubuntu side by side with Windows (it automatically detects the windows partition).
When you are done with the installation, don't forget to enter the HP BIOS (mine is F10), go to the boot section, hit the boot manager or OS manager and make sure Ubuntu is placed atop the windows OS (key to changing mine was F5 and F6). Save changes exit. Viola.
If any issues pop up, kindly use the recovery mode and boot normal from there. I hope this helps Enjoy!

Comment: no dedicated video, just the i3 with 520 graphics. safe mode hangs at black screen with UBUNTU, no mouse cursor, no desktop with try/install dialog.

Comment: Hello. Most of this answer has nothing to do with the question that was asked.