# Ubuntu 20.04 sudden boot failure: platform device creation failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

My laptop had a sudden issue booting.  Not sure how it got to this as I have not touched anything or even updated the OS (running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS).  It has dual boot Windows and Ubuntu.

The massage I get reads something like:

> [  0.368857] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem ....] 
> [  0.368867] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16 
> /dev/sd5: clean, 290838/21807104 files, 7342185/87200000 blocks

and then it just hangs there.

I have tried several times to boot in recovery mode but I do not get anywhere.  I have managed to get the `lsblk` information from the commend prompt (root from the Recovery menu) and it looks as follows:

[image: lsblk from command prompt]

I believe the *sda3* partition is the Windows partition while the *sda5* is the Ubuntu partition.  However, once in the command prompt I the only folders I see is are:

> .cache 
> .local 
> snap

I do not seem to see my fodlers there.

I also tried [disbling the TPM in the BIOS/UEFI as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926738/cant-load-failed-to-claim-resource-1) (second answer) but now it seems to get stuck in a message that says:

> [  0.128223] x86/cpu SGX disabled by BIOS 
> /dev/sd5: clean, 290844/21807104 files, 7344010/87200000 blocks

Any suggestions that will not require me re-installing Ubuntu are welcomed.

Comment: did you see [SGX disabled by BIOS message on Ubuntu 20.04 booting](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418997/782725)?

Comment: I had not, but once I tried, the laptop would get stuck again.  I am guessing, without much authority though, that it may be the command that is coming right after that sequence that is the culprit.  However, I have no way to verify this.  I have since reformatted the entire computer as I was able to access the files (by booting using a flash drive) and backing things up.  I have now created a better partition table so that if the boot partition is lost, I will still be able to recover the home folder.  Also, I got rid of the virus; I got rid of Windows altogether ;)