Ubuntu is not booting in the HP laptop with i5 6th gen
I am getting the below error while booting.
Sometimes system is logging in, but sometimes it is stuck in the same error and not booting. Installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Please help. dual booted with Windows 11 as primary. Also, grub is always loading in Windows. Tried many options and methods on the web.
Thanks in advance for your kind help.
[
[
0.380139] =
0.380151] UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-hwe-6.5-34pCLi/linux-h
we-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/acpi/acpi_watchdog.c:140:25 0.380165] shift exponent -1 is negative
[
[
0.380257]
0.380272] platform wdat_wdt: failed to claim resource 5: [mem 0x00000000-0x
0.380282] ACPI: watchdog: Device creation failed: -16
[ 0.421534] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not UB.TPLD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.XHC.RH
[ 0.421561] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC.CR01. PLD due to previous e rror (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)
0.454105] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000 -Oxfed40fff]
[ 0.454116] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16 /dev/sdag: clean, 220754/915712 files, 3579318/3662080 blocks [11.767353] lis31v02d: unknown sensor type 0x0


If you're still running 14.10, it's well overdue time to update. 14.10 is end of life and out of scope for questions on askubuntu

using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Is this any use? https://askubuntu.com/questions/926738/cant-load-failed-to-claim-resource-1

Have you updated firmware from HP for UEFI to latest version available. And if SSD, update its firmware also? From live installer you can see firmware versions: udisksctl status &
inxi -d 
